# VR Headset support in linux?

Tags: application-development, hardware

I volunteer for a non-profit, making, and repairing kid friendly art & science displays. Some college kid has just developed a VR experience, and requested we purchase a HTC Vive Virtual Reality System - 99HAHZ044-00.

Inevitably, I will end up being the maintainer,(when the semester ends) and developer of this system, so I would like to know what I might expect for support, for VR systems like this one, in ubuntu.  Are there C/C++ libraries I should look at? Are there VR Packages I should look at? Is this Ubuntu supported hardware?

Comment: You might be able to use [Valve's OpenVR SDK](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr). I'd imagine that official support for it from Canonical won't be coming anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

A person going by the name of Norbert http://www.vronlinux.com/articles/i-am-using-vr-on-linux-with-my-vive-and-vrui.37 got the Vive going using Vrui http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/Vrui/Download.html